# Some relationship-status not getting returned when clearly visible on profile

Tags: facebook-graph-api, relationship, status

When using the open graph api to list - all friends by relationship_status some friends are getting returned empty for relationship_status. I have the right permissions set as most friends relationship_status are returned if not set to private.

question of the friends in question that are getting returned empty, I can clearly go onto the profile and view their relationship_status. My only guess as I have searched around would be that they have it set so I personally can see it but others it is private??

requested information:

It's not just doing it in my code but also in the Graph API Explorer.

Example:
->/me?mfields=id,name,friends.uid( person querying ).fields(relationship_status)

returns the relationship for people that have it set viewable to me but for some reason certain people that I can go on their profile and look right at their relationship_status when queried returns nothing???

Comment: If you can provide an example of your current code, this will make it much easier for others to provide assistance.